# Is it possible to transform data during a migration with AWS's DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration

Is it possible to transform actual data while performing a migration with the AWS Data Migration Service? I'm trying to migrate data from PostgreSQL to DynamoDB and to append a prefix to the data that is brought over with DMS. From what I can tell, it looks like all of the transformation rules that are available in the migration task only apply to components of the table themselves (column names, table names, schema names).

Basically I would like something like this in Postgres
`ID:123` to become `ID:pre_123` in Dynamo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up an object mapping rule for a column to be “value” = “pre_${columnName}” or whatever the actual syntax is. More about mappings with examples is given in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html

Comment: Object-mapping! Thank you!!

Comment: Here's a link to the specific section: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html#CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.ObjectMapping

Answer (score -3):

To my knowledge, yes you can transform data with DMS.