# can we change values being migrated with aws DMS migration service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-migration, aws-dms

My use case is i want to migration data from rds mysql to dynamodb but i also want the data to be modified during migration.

I tried like this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/images/datarep-Tasks-conditional1.png)  but modification did not happened.

reference  ->
[similar question but it didn't helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893699/is-it-possible-to-transform-data-during-a-migration-with-awss-dms)